# Realize $M \otimes_A N$ is an $B-$ module where $M$ is an $A$ module and $N$ is an $AB$ bimodule

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, tensor-products

As title indicates. This is actually a partial exercise in MacDonalds. But most of these relevant exercises boils down to constructing some natural map and using universal property to argue the isomorphisms.

Anyways my problem is this very loose statement that $M \otimes_A N$ is actually a $B-$module.

So I thought I just write out the free module that would be generated by $M \times N$, $C = \{ \sum_{i,j = 1}^n a_ib_j(m_i,n_{ij})  : n = |M \times N|\}$. Now I feel like the answering is staring at me in this sum, but I can't draw out the answer atm. I honestly think the answer lies in the part "$b_j(m_i$" where the $b_js$ are "touching" the $m_i$ is the reason.

Comment: What you need is to define the multiplication $b\cdot (m\otimes n)$ for $b\in B$ and $m\otimes n \in M\otimes_A N$.

Comment: @chankifung, u mean since $N$ is a $B-$mod, then $m \otimes bn = b(m \otimes n)$? Is that sufficient?

Comment: Yes, you need to check that $ b\cdot (m \otimes n)=m \otimes bn$ is a well-defined may using the property of tensor products.

Comment: @chankifung, do u mean the bilinear properties? Isn't that inherent in the tensor product? Why do I have to check that?

Comment: yes, basically the well-defineness follows directly from the definition. And now you see how the $B$ module structure is defined?

Comment: @chankifung, I think so, but it looks like all we are using is the property that $N$ is a $B-$module and you telling me to first define $b \cdot (m\otimes n)$ is the initial action of $B$ on $M \otimes_A N$ correct?

Comment: yes, i think so